# Android Tablet App Template

Tags: android, templates, user-interface, tablet

Before starting to develop an app I was asked to design it in PS or something similar, so I was searching for standard templates for an Android based Tablet App. I googled it and searched here but found nothing, someone knows where I can get this template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there are no real "templates" for this, however I can give you a list of general dimensions that tablets will have. You should be able to work with those.

> Just like phones, tablets have all sorts of dimensions and sizes. Here
>   is a quick list of different models with their respective sizes and
>   dimensions:
>
> - Samsung Galaxy Tab 10.1 3G - 10.1 inches, 1280 x 800 pixels
> - Samsung P1000 Galaxy Tab - 7.0 inches, 600 x 1024 pixels
> - Dell Streak 7 - 7-inch 800×480
> - Motorola Xoom - 10.1-inch, 1280×800
> - Viewsonic G - 10.1-inchs 1024×600
>
> These are the dimensions you'll find most often.

---

After doing some searching I think I found a few links you might find usefull:

[Several design tools for Android interfaces](http://webdesignledger.com/tools/useful-tools-and-kits-for-android-developers)

[Honeycomb stencils](http://www.zurb.com/playground/honeycomb-stencils)

Comment: Thanks for answering, it is just a sketch, I was going to take the 10.1 inchs tablets as standart. For a template I was searching maybe some psd files with standard toolbar, a standard tablet screen, etc...

Comment: Ah that's not so hard I guess, simply pull a basic interface picture from Google, and remove the part in the middle where you'll show the app. Voila, a template.

Comment: yes I know, but maybe someone knew a pack with that done, with standard buttons, the bar, etc..

Comment: Found what you are looking for. I changed my answer.